# PyTorch has CUDA version 10.2 and torch_sparse has CUDA version 11.1 on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, pytorch

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04 and it looks like CUDA10.2 does not support the latest version of Ubuntu.

Does anyone know how can I fix this problem?

The full error:

> RuntimeError: Detected that PyTorch and torch_sparse were compiled
> with different CUDA versions. PyTorch has CUDA version 10.2 and
> torch_sparse has CUDA version 11.1. Please reinstall the torch_sparse
> that matches your PyTorch install.

Thanks!

Comment: Probably either by building your own torch with the toolchain versions you have or downgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 (maybe even in a container or virtual environment like docker)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have CUDA 11.1 in Ubuntu but Pytorch doesn't support this version yet (the latest supported today is 10.2).

One solution is downgrading your CUDA:

```
$ sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-450 
$ sudo sudo apt autoremove 
$ sudo reboot 
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-440-server
$ sudo reboot 
$ nvidia-smi 

Thu Oct 15 12:52:24 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 440.95.01    Driver Version: 440.95.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

CUDA 11 support is planned with Pytorch 1.7.